# How to Select multiple record in Ms sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have List myint = new List();

i want to select multiple like productid = 1 , productid = 2

how to select multiple products

```
select * from product where ProductId = 1,2
```

using ms sql server

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? And what type of application is it? `.net`?

Answer (score 1):

You can write this query in two ways,

```
SELECT * FROM Products 
WHERE ProductID IN (1,2)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE ProductID = 1
  OR  ProductID = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from product where ProductId in(1,2)
```